# Credit card payment implementation for windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, credit-card

As per requirement we need to create a KIOSKI application with limited feature on windows platform. We are planning   create the app as windows store app.  This app will have credit card payment option. Still I don’t know how to achieve it.  I think we have to use some payment gateways for this. I don’t have previous experience with credit card implementation.

1. Can we implement credit card processing from a windows 8.1 app store app?
2. Which payment gateway I have to choose for this? The application is for US people.

If you have a solution on this matter please share and guide me to the right path.
Any help would be appreciable.

Regards

Ranish

Comment: It really depends on what you wanna do... What shall be purchased? Digital goods? Or physical products?

Comment: Actually through KIOSK application user can view and Buy products. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ranish Did you find the solution i have a similar problem

Comment: @Eldho I didn't get a proper solution yet. Still looking for a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://www.bluepay.com/developers/api-documentation/csharp/. We've used it in our apps; they provide all of the processing & gateway work, including a system for storing card details on their servers for recurring payments. Your app sends requests via HTTP POST. Pricing is reasonable.